# HTML5 Canvas flickering, don't think a buffer will work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Right now, I have a JavaScript function that goes through a 24x24 grid and draws a random color at each location.  It works fine in Chrome, however there's this horrible flickering in Firefox.  Now, normally it would seem like a buffer would fix it, however the canvas is actually invisible, and I just set it as the background using `canvas.toDataURL();` once all the squares are updated.  Any thoughts as to why it isn't working?

Edit:

Here's the code in question:

```
  window.onload=function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("background"); //canvas is assigned the ID of background
  var canvasBuffer = canvas;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 30);
      };
  })();


  var fps = 30;
  var ar = 0;
  var ag = 0;
  var ab = 0;
  var br = 0;
  var bg = 0;
  var bb = 0;
  var redmod = .6;
  var greenmod = 1.1;
  var bluemod = 1.2;
  var count = 0;
  var coords = new Array(8);


  //create an 8x8 matrix of value pairs (current value and target value)
  for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
      coords[i] = new Array(8);
      for (var j = 0; j < 24; j++) {
          coords[i][j] = new Array(2);
          coords[i][j][0] = randomColor();
          coords[i][j][1] = randomColor();
          ctx.fillStyle = "#" + coords[i][j][0];        
          ctx.fillRect(i * 20, j * 20, 20, 20);
      }
    }

  function assignToDiv(){ // sets the canvas as the background of two divs
    dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("intro").style.background='url('+dataUrl+')'
    document.getElementById("nav").style.background='url('+dataUrl+')'
  }

  function animate() {
      setTimeout(function () {
          requestAnimFrame(animate);
          requestAnimFrame(assignToDiv);

          // Drawing code goes here
          // changes the general color over time
          if (count == 256){
              redmod = .4;
              greenmod = .8;
              bluemod = 1;
          }
          else if (count == 512){
              redmod = 1.4;
              greenmod = .8;
              bluemod = .6;
          }
          else if (count == 768){
              redmod = 1.3;
              greenmod = .5;
              bluemod = .6;
          }
          else if (count == 1024){
              redmod = 1.1;
              greenmod = .3;
              bluemod = .5;
          }
          else if (count == 1280){
              redmod = .6;
              greenmod = 1.1;
              bluemod = 1.2;
              count = 0;
          }
          count++;
          //choose 3 squares to change        
          for (var m = 0; m < 3; m++){

              var r = parseInt(Math.random() * 24);
              var c = parseInt(Math.random() * 24);

              coords[c][r][1] = randomColor();
          }
          //update each square
          for (var k = 0; k < 24; k++) {
              for (var l = 0; l < 24; l++) {
                  //make sure all colors are 6 digits long
                  while (coords[k][l][0].length<6){
                      coords[k][l][0]= "0" + coords[k][l][0];
                  }
                  while (coords[k][l][1].length<6){
                      coords[k][l][1]= "0" + coords[k][l][1];
                  }

                  //convert the red, green, and blue values back to dec
                  ar = parseInt(coords[k][l][0].substring(0,2),16);
                  ag = parseInt(coords[k][l][0].substring(2,4),16);
                  ab = parseInt(coords[k][l][0].substring(4,6),16)

                  br = parseInt(coords[k][l][1].substring(0,2),16);
                  bg = parseInt(coords[k][l][1].substring(2,4),16);
                  bb = parseInt(coords[k][l][1].substring(4,6),16);              

                  //move the current color closer to the target color
                  ar = parseInt(ar + (br - ar)/fps);
                  ag = parseInt(ag + (bg - ag)/fps);
                  ab = parseInt(ab + (bb - ab)/fps);
                  //put it pack to hex
                  var RR = ((ar.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+ar.toString(16):ar.toString(16));
                  var GG = ((ag.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+ag.toString(16):ag.toString(16));
                  var BB = ((ab.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+ab.toString(16):ab.toString(16));

                  coords[k][l][0] = RR + GG + BB;

                  ctx.fillStyle = "#" + coords[k][l][0];
                  ctx.fillRect(k * 20, l * 20, 20, 20);
              }
          }


      }, 1000 / fps);
  }

  // create a random color object {red,green,blue}
  function randomColor() {
    var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 128 * redmod);
    var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 128 * greenmod);
    var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 128 * bluemod);
    var avg = red * .3 + green * .6 + blue * .1;

    red = parseInt(red * .5 + avg * .5);
    green = parseInt(green * .5 + avg * .5);
    blue = parseInt(blue * .5 + avg * .5);

      var redhex = ((red.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+red.toString(16):red.toString(16));
      var greenhex = ((green.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+green.toString(16):green.toString(16));
      var bluehex = ((blue.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+blue.toString(16):blue.toString(16));

      return (redhex + greenhex + bluehex);
  }


  animate();
  assignToDiv();

  }
```

Then the canvas is placed at the top of the body:

```
    <canvas id="background" width=480 height=480></canvas>
```

and in the CSS:

```
#background {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Hard to debug without code. My only advice with the given (lack of) info is that you should use requestAnimationFrame: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: Might have something to do with the way that Firefox renders data URLs or background images and not with canvas itself. If you're not actually witnessing the flickering happen on a canvas then the issue most likely doesn't lie with the canvas.

Comment: Ok, updated it with the code.  And how would I tell if it's on the canvas or not?

Comment: Actually, @izuriel, that seems to be exactly what it is.  I went into the debugger, and the flicker happens after `document.getElementById("intro").style.background='url('+dataUrl+')';` is called.  Do you know of any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem is that you're replacing 2 of your element backgrounds at 60fps.**

Instead of constantly replacing the background of "intro" and "nav", layer a canvas element under both intro & nav. Then draw on those underlying canvases.

Comment: Interesting... Just to clarify, you're saying to basically create canvases the same size and shape as intro and nav, and then set them to be behind the text?

Comment: Yes...You would have 2 canvases and 2 contexts.  You would do fillStyle="#"+coords[k][l][0] and fillRect(k*20,l*20,20,20) to both "background" canvases.  Canvases can handle the rapid redrawing while html backgrounds cause flickering.